# UICollectionView cells disappearing when deleting items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally. Each item can be swiped upward to delete. This is done through a pan gesture that inserted on the UICollectionViewCell. The animation code is ad follows:

```
let translation = gesture.translation(in: contentView)

        if gesture.state == .changed {
            tabView.center.y += translation.y
            gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: contentView)
        } else if gesture.state == .ended {
            if tabView.center.y < contentView.center.y {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.tabView.frame.origin.y = -self.tabView.frame.size.height
                }) { (_) in
                    self.delegate?.didSwipeCell(at: self.indexPath())
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the collection view delegate conformance

```
func didSwipeCell(at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
       guard indexPath != nil else {
           return
       }

       self.tabs.remove(at: indexPath!.row)
       self.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
   }
```

This produces the following effect:

[image: Animation and deletion in progress]

As you can see, I have 6 items in my collection view, however, when swiping away and deleting the first four items for example, the last 2 items disappear. I have not been able to figure out the reason of the disappearance of those items. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the indexPath when you are deleting an item. Is that correct index are you deleting?

Comment: Yes that is the correct index

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by overriding prepareForReuse() in the UICollectionViewCell and setting the frame origin back to (0,0)